# Prove (or disprove) $T(a,b)T(c,d)\leq T(ac,bd)$?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Let $T : [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$. A $t$-norm is a function $T$ with properties:

1. $ T (x, 1) = x$
2. If $y\leq z$ then $T(x,y)\leq T(x,z)$
3. $T (x, y) = T (y, x) $
4. $T (x, T (y, z)) = T (T (x, y), z) $

Prove (or disprove) $T(a,b)T(c,d)\leq T(ac,bd)$?

I don't have idea how to start the proof (if provable). I try to find the example as below, and it's holds.

Let $T(x,y)=\min(x,y)$. Pick $a=0.1$, $b=0.3$, $c=0.5$, and $d=0.2$.

\begin{align}
T(a,b)T(c,d)&=\min(0.1,0.3)\min(0.5,0.2)=0.1\cdot 0.2 = 0.02.\\
T(ac,bd)&= \min(0.1\cdot 0.5, 0.3\cdot 0.2) = \min(0.05, 0.06)=0.05.
\end{align}

So, $T(a,b)T(c,d)\leq T(ac,bd)$

Any idea to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $T(x,y):=\max(x+y-1,0)$.
Then \begin{align}T(x,1)&=\max(x,0)=x\\
y\le z&\implies x+y-1\le x+z-1\implies T(x,y)\le T(x,z)\\
T(x,y)&=\max(y+x-1,0)=T(y,x)\\
T(x,T(y,z))&=T(T(x,y),z)
\end{align} the last by some handwaving, checking cases $x+y+z<2$, etc.

Now let $a=b=c=d=3/5$. Then $$T(a,b)T(c,d)=1/25\ne 0=T(ac,bd)$$